# PostgreSQL: after import some data, if insert there is error - IntegrityError duplicate key value violates unique constraint "place_country_pkey"

Tags: postgresql

When I import some data to PostgreSQL through PhpPgAdmin there is all fine.
But when I try later to insert some data to populated before tables I get an error:

> **IntegrityError:** duplicate key value violates unique constraint "place_country_pkey"

And this is happens only with prepopulated tables.

Here is my SQL:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS place_country CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE place_country (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
    country_en VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    country_ru VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    country_ua VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO place_country VALUES(1,'Ukraine','Украина','Україна');
```

How to avoid this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try not inserting the "1". IIRC, in Postgres, when you define a column as SERIAL, it means that it will auto-generate an ID with a counter to automatically populate that column. So use:

```
INSERT INTO place_country (country_en, country_ru, country_ua) VALUES (Ukraine','Украина','Україна');
```

Which is a good practice anyway, BTW (explicitly naming the columns in an INSERT, I mean).